# What do the auth method and welcome files in web.xml indicate?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

What do the auth method and welcome files in web.xml indicate?

Answer (score 4):

The `<auth-method>` defines the method a web application authenticates it's users. You can choose between different methods, such as *BASIC* (basic http authentication), *FORM* (form based authentication) or *CLIENT-CERT* (authentication based on a client certificate)

See [this page for detailed information on authentication methods](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security).

The `<welcome-file-list>` defines default pages that a server sends to a client if the request URI points to a directory.